# Python - How to pull an attribute out of list of custom objects and convert it to a float?

Tags: python, lambda, floating-point, attributes

I am a novice Python user so I hope I haven't missed something basic but I feel I've done my due diligence in trying to research this problem on my own so here goes.

In brief, I am writing a program that will analyze sports statistics and ultimately generate a rating for the strength of each team based on the chosen statistics.

I can successfully read in simple csv files and I'm reasonably happy with the custom object class I have created to store the statistics as attributes for each team but I am running in to an issue when I go to calculate the rating. Essentially, I need to sort all the teams by each statistic I am interested in, rank the teams by this statistic and assign a point value for the rank of each one. This will produce a cumulative rating score based on the rank for each statistic. However, I'm having some issues in getting the statistic value as a float which I think I need to do in order to sort properly.

Here's the code I've tried:

I've created a team object as seen below. This version is stripped down of most of the attributes for ease of reading but the additional attributes are all very similar.

```
    class team(object):
        def__init__(self,teamName="",passOffYc=0, passOffAya=0):
            self.teamName = teamName
            self.passOffYc = passOffYc
            self.passOffAya = passOffAya
            self.score = 0
```

These objects are constructed from a csv file that has a header with the statistical categories and each row represents a team and its stats. I am reading in the file using csv.DictReader like this:

```
    league= []

    with open(passoffense) as csvfile:
        statreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in statreader:     
            newTeam = team(row["Tm"],row["Y/C"],row["AY/A"])
            print(newTeam, "added")
            league.append(newTeam)
```

At this point I think I have a list called league that contains a team object for each row in the csv file and the teamname, passOffYc, and passOffAya attributes have taken the values for the row elements Tm, Y/C, and AY/A. These are the team name, Yards per Catch, and Average Yards per Attempt so the second two are all decimal numbers.

To try to create the score for each team object, I'd like to sort the league list first by passOffYc, determine the rank of each team, and then repeat for passOffAya and so on for all the attributes in the full version of the program.

I've attempted two different implementations of this trying to understand attrgetter or lambda functions.

My attrgetter thoughts are something like this:

```
    sortedTeams = sorted(league, key = attrgetter("passOffYc"))
```

My understanding is that this would sort the list called league according to the attribute passOffYc but the issue I'm encountering is that the sort is not producing the expected output.

If passOffYc was 19, 23, 14, 7, and 9, I am expecting the sort to result in 7, 9, 14, 19, 23. However it will end up sorting as 14, 19, 23, 7, 9. My research has led me to believe this is because the values are strings and not integers (or more accurately floats as some values have decimals) Not quite sure how to fix this I tried:

```
    sortedTeams = sorted(league, key = float(attrgetter("passOffYc"))
```

But this gives me the error:

```
    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'operator.attrgetter'
```

So apparently it isn't a string and instead is an operator.attrgetter object. I haven't been able to figure out how to get the key for the sorted function to the float type so I also tried using lambda functions I read about while searching:

```
    sortedTeams = sorted(league, key = lambda team: float(team.passOffYc))
```

This seems very close to what I'd like to happen as it does sort properly but then I run in to a scaling problem. Since I have more than 20 attributes to sort by in the full version of my program I'd like to avoid needing to type the above statement 20 times to accommodate each attribute.

I thought of trying to define a function something to the effect of:

```
    def score(stat):
        sortedTeams = sorted(league, key = lambda team: float(team.stat))
```

I thought this would allow me to pass in to the lambda function which stat I want to sort by but I then get the error:

```
    AttributeError: 'team' object has no attribute 'stat'
```

I think this is because it may not be possible to pass an argument to a lambda function or that I'm not understanding something because I also tried:

```
    sortedTeams = sorted(league, key = lambda team, stat=stat: float(team.stat))
```

Which resulted in the same error. Whew! If you're still reading this thank you for wading through my essay. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Once I get the sorting to work properly and can scale it I intend to enumerate the sorted lists to obtain the ranks and I'm beginning to think about strategies to address ties. Thank you again for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create the original team entries with float contents:

```
newTeam = team(row["Tm"],float(row["Y/C"]),float(row["AY/A"]))
```

If instead you want to pursue the lambda approach you can use:

```
sortedTeams = sorted(league, key = lambda team: float(attrgetter("passOffYc")(team)))
```

This could similarly be used in your function score function.  What you were missing is that attrgetter returns a function.  You can then call that function by passing it an argument (in this case team).  Then that result can be passed to float.  In that function you could use:

```
lambda team: float(attrgetter(stat)(team))
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't considered that getting the correct type is probably best done upon creation! I also appreciate the example of how to get attrgetter and a lambda function working together. This fully answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you whant to pass a string name of desired field into function. If that is right, then instead of:

```
def score(stat):
    sortedTeams = sorted(league, key = lambda team: float(team.stat))
```

Try this:

```
def score(stat):
    sortedTeams = sorted(league, key = lambda team: float(getattr(team, stat)))
```

Some explanation. `team.stat` - accessing an attribute with name `"stat"` for object `team`. `getattr(team, stat)` - accessing an attribute with name given in the `stat` variable for object `team`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, this is very useful to understand going forward while using lambda functions!